# Partial derivative confusion

Tags: calculus

For the function whose graph is a paraboloid given by

$z = x^2 + y^2/4$

I know that the level curve represents an ellipse. I also know that the parametrization of this curve in the form $x = x(t)$, $y = y(t)$ is

$x(t) = \cos(t)$
and
$y(t) = 2\sin(t)$

In class, my professor said to compute the derivative of $z$ as a function of $t$, or $∂z/∂t.$
however, he stopped right there, saying the answer is too simple.

Is the derivative with respect to t 0? because deriving

$z= \cos^2(t) + 2\sin^2(t)/4$

with respect to $t$ yields $0$, because both of those sums are a constant number.

Is this the simplicity he was referring to?

Comment: $z= \cos^2(t) + 4\sin^2(t)/4=1$ and not $z= \cos^2(t) + 2\sin^2(t)/4$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That parameterisation is for a level curve of that paraboloid. In other words, the parameterisation is assuming that the value of $z$ is to be held constant. This means that regardless of how $t$ varies, $z$ will not change: it is constant.

This is why the derivative $\frac{\partial z}{\partial t}$ is zero, because $z$ is fixed with respect to $t$. I would say yes, this is likely the simplicity he saw, it sounds like he realised this partway through what he was saying.

Comment: Yes! In my notes, we mentioned that it describes a level curve at z = 1. So since z stays fixed, there is no rate of change. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Notice that $z = \text{cos}^2 \ x + \frac{4 \text{sin}^2\ x}{4} = 1 $. Which means for each $t$ taken the function is constant. So you and your teacher are right.